Smoothness condition for complete intersection to be k3 surface
I have a question which is simultaneously about the definition of of a smooth complete intersection and about the proof of the following claim.
We have the following claim: a smooth complete intersection of type $(d_1, \cdots, d_n)$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+2}$ is a K3 surface if and only if $\sum d_i = n+3$. If the hypersurfaces $F_1, \cdots, F_n$ of degrees $d_1, \cdots, d_n$ give the smooth complete intersection, then the most natural approach I thought of was to look at the short exact sequences
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{F_1}(-d_1) \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^{n+2}}|_{F_1} \to \Omega_{F_1} \to 0
$$
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{F_1 \cap F_2}(-d_2) \to \Omega_{F_1}|_{F_1 \cap F_2} \to \Omega_{F_1 \cap F_2} \to 0
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n}(-d_n) \to \Omega_{F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_{n-1}}|_{F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n} \to \Omega_{F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n} \to 0
$$
and inductively show that $\omega_{F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n} \cong \mathcal{O}_{F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n}$ if and only if $\sum d_i = n+3$.
However, my question about this is the following: in order to do this proof, I need to know all of the above conormal exact sequences are actually short exact sequences. When you have $Y \subset X$ being smooth varieties, then you know
$$
0 \to \mathcal{I}_Y/\mathcal{I}_Y^2 \to \Omega_X|_Y \to \Omega_Y \to 0
$$
is exact, but when things are non-smooth you can have failure of left exactness.
This leads me to ask: what is, then, the definition of smooth complete intersection beyond the generators of ideals definition. At first, I took smooth complete intersection to simply mean that $0 \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a regular value of the map
$$
\mathbb{C}^{n+3} \setminus \{0 \} \to \mathbb{C}^n, \text{ where } (z_1, \cdots, z_{n+3}) \mapsto (P_1(z), \cdots, P_n(z))
$$
where $P_i$ is the homogeneous polynomial defining $F_i$. But then this doesn't guarantee that even each individual $F_i$ is smooth. Any clarification on the definition of smooth complete intersection in terms of this "smoothness discussion," or an alternative proof that circumvents the need for each subintersection being smooth, would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

A subvariety $X\subset\Bbb P^n$ of codimension $c$ is a complete intersection iff the homogeneous ideal of $X$ is generated by exactly $c$ elements.
A subvariety $X\subset\Bbb P^n$ is smooth iff the corank of the Jacobian is equal to the dimension of the variety at every point. (There are, of course, other useful equivalent definitions, but let me stick to this one since it's most applicable to our situation.)
Your definitions are equivalent to these. A workaround I like for the problem you're experiencing involves the Koszul complex.
Let $X\subset\Bbb P^n$ be a complete intersection with homogeneous ideal $I$ generated by $f_1,\cdots,f_r$ of degrees $d_1,\cdots,d_r$ respectively. I claim $\omega_X\cong\mathcal{O}_X(-n-1+\sum_{i=1}^r d_i)$. The Koszul resolution of $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the total complex of the tensor product $\bigotimes\left(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-d_i)\stackrel{f_i}{\to}\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}\right)$; as the $f_i$ form a regular sequence, this is an exact complex, and hence a finite free resolution of $\mathcal{O}_X$. As locally free sheaves of finite rank are acyclic for sheaf ext and $\omega_X\cong\mathcal{E}xt^{n-r}(\mathcal{O}_X,\omega_{\Bbb P^n})$, we may compute $\omega_X$ to be the cokernel of $$\bigoplus_{j=1}^r \mathcal{O}_X(-n-1-d_j+\sum_{i=1}^r d_i) \to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-n-1+\sum_{i=1}^r d_i)$$ where the $j^{th}$ basis vector on the left is sent to $f_j$ on the right. But this is just the twist by $-n-1+\sum_{i=1}^r d_i$ of the natural free resolution of $\mathcal{O}_X$, so the result follows.

There is a minor problem with your first approach --- though the intersection $V(f_1,\dots,f_{r-1})$ is smooth along $X$, it may be singular away from $X$.

@Sasha Thank you for pointing that out.

Yes, that is the issue I was concerned about. Then one must proceed with the Koszul complex approach right?

Not necessarily. You can just restrict to the complement of the singular locus of the intermediate complete intersection and consider the next one as a hypersurface in this complement.

Ah, I see. So if we let $X_i = Z(F_1) \cap \cdots \cap Z(F_i)$, and $X_i^{sm}$ to be the smooth locus of $X_i$, then we have the chain
$$
X_1^{sm} \supset X_2^{sm} \supset \cdots \supset X_{n-1}^{sm} \supset X_n.
$$

@maxo: Maybe it is a bit better to consider $S = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (Sing(X_i))$ and the chan formed by $X_i \setminus S$.
